# display:block, width:100% & center aligned

Tags: css, tablelayout

I have a table in an email that shows when `(max-width :600px)`

CSS:

```
table[class="advert-container show"] { display: block !important; }
```

Both tables have with=100%, But bottom table with the class "show" seems to align left,

What is block doing to my table? :(

Here is my JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/QPhEp/1/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

actually `display:block` display the element as a block-level element (like paragraphs and headers) [Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

Comment: actually still confuse what u want update your question plz and elaborate it.

Comment: the bottom table has display:none until the media query 600px comes into action then it shows the table with display:block. How can i show it with out the display rule?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
table[class="advert-container show"] { display: table !important; }
td.ad {  margin:10px; float:left; }
```

​instead of block.

I have more improve the style in this new fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/zJacq/1/

```
table[class="advert-container show"] { display: table; }
td.ad { padding:10px; }
```

​

Comment: Hi, the table is set to display:none before it the media reaches 600px